# Eclipse cannot find Android device - Motorola RAZR HD

Tags: android, macos, adb, motorola

stack virgin, please be gentle.

Recently installed Eclipse w/ ADT bundle & adb cannot find my USB device (Motorola RAZR HD).  I've run through the following so far:

1. adb kill-server -> adb start-server -> adb devices
2. uncheck/check usb debugging on device
3. restart device (both unplugged/plugged)
4. restart Eclipse
5. from IDE -> DDMS -> restart adb

Most of the posts here deal with the above.  Others are Windows/Linux related.

I'm running OS X 10.7.5 & Android Developer Tools Build: v21.0.1-543035.  The documentation found here:

http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

... conveniently says "If you're developing on Mac OS X, it just works. Skip this step."  When referring to setting up a hardware device.  I typically agree with this statement, but in this case, it's not helpful.

I am also running EasyTether Pro through the device and suspect the drivers for this application are the culprit but could be dead wrong.  I am typically dead wrong ergo question here.

Anywho - if anyone has seen an issue with this particular device or has any magic to help that would be rad.

I would prefer not to reinstall Eclipse/ADT but if that gets the job done, so be it.

Comment: Have you tried another device, to see if it's a "general issue" or just the Motorola RAZR HD?

Comment: Found new link - researching now:

Comment: http://intohand.com/archive?tag=android

Comment: I will be self-answering this question when my < 10 rep 7 hours have expired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EasyTetherPro is the culprit.  There are several articles online about this that I have now found.

http://qtcstation.com/2011/04/warning-easytether-will-break-adb/
http://intohand.com/archive?tag=android

Answer (score 1):

First of all start with the command line and once everything works involve Eclipse and other stuff.

You have to add the device **USB Vendor ID** to `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`:

```
$ echo '0x1234' >> ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
```

Replace `0x1234` by the real id.
If you don't know the **USB Vendor ID** you can use ***System Information*** to obtain it.
Once added, proceed with the steps you were doing (kill, restart, etc.).

Comment: EasyTether is the culprit.  ADB on Mac OS X stops recognizing the attached device after installing EasyTether driver

Do not follow this advice if you are not a software developer who uses the Android SDK on Mac. Otherwise run "sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/EasyTetherUSBEthernet.kext" to unload the EasyTether driver manually. Load it again with kextload when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to run the command sequence

```
    adb kill-server
    adb start-server
    adb devices sequence
```

using the 'sudo' command.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the dumbest answer ever, but.. as I have a USB port in the back of my laptop and besides it there's the network port, I had connected the Phone to the Network port instead of the USB. Just please double check I almost install Windows because of this. duh!